# Unable to concatenate strings separated by comma

Tags: batch-file, concatenation, dos

I'm being driven crazy by a stupidly simple problem that is eating up my time. I just want to append strings separated by comma, but the comma doesn't get appended. Below is my batch file snippet:

```
set MissingParams=
set SwitchURL=
set TrustStore=
if 0%SwitchURL%==0 (set MissingParams=SwitchURL)
  if 0%TrustStore%==0 (
    if not 0%MissingParams%==0 (        
         set MissingParams=%MissingParams%,
      )
      set MissingParams=%MissingParams%TrustStore
  )
```

After runnin this script when I echo `%MisingParams%`, the expected value is `SwitchURL,TrustStore` but it simply prints

`SwitchURLTrustStore`.

```
D:\deleteme>echo %MissingParams%
SwitchURLTrustStore
```

For debugging, when I introduced some echo statements in the batch file, the results are even more bizzare:

```
set MissingParams=
if 0%SwitchURL%==0 (set MissingParams=SwitchURL)
  if 0%TrustStore%==0 (
    if not 0%MissingParams%==0 (    
      echo MissingParams=%MissingParams%
      set MissingParams=%MissingParams%,
      echo MissingParams=%MissingParams%
    )
    set MissingParams=%MissingParams%TrustStore
    echo MissingParams=%MissingParams%
  )
```

When I run the above script it prints

```
MissingParams=SwitchURL
MissingParams=SwitchURL
MissingParams=SwitchURL
```

And when I echo the value from the command prompt, as before I get `SwitchURLTrustStore`

```
D:\deleteme>echo %MissingParams%
SwitchURLTrustStore
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This is frustrating me to no end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard parenthesis/delayedExpansion problem.

The simple rule is %var% are expanded **before** a parenthesis block is executed(while parsing).

If you need the var-expansion later, you should use the delayed expansion.
Explained in **set /?**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set MissingParams=
set SwitchURL=
set TrustStore=
if 0!SwitchURL!==0 (set MissingParams=SwitchURL)
  if 0!TrustStore!==0 (
    if not 0!MissingParams!==0 (        
         set MissingParams=!MissingParams!,
      )
      set MissingParams=!MissingParams!TrustStore
  )
```

Comment: It's the delayed expansion style, explained at **set /?**

Answer (score 1):

Sort of looks like a scoping problem.  I was able to work around this by branching with a goto which works. Here's my version with extra debug crap:

```
@echo off
set MissingParams=
set SwitchURL=
set TrustStore=
if "%SwitchURL%"=="" (set MissingParams=SwitchURL)
echo MissingParams1 is %MissingParams%
if "%TrustStore%" EQU "" (GOTO :BRANCH1)
:RESUME
  echo MissingParams3 is %MissingParams%
  set MissingParams=%MissingParams%TrustStore
  echo MissingParams4 is %MissingParams%
)
echo MissingParamsF is %MissingParams%
GOTO :eof

:BRANCH1
if "%MissingParams%" NEQ "" (set MissingParams=%MissingParams%,)
GOTO RESUME
```